# Software to develop C#/ASP.NET in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, visual-studio

Is there any software (similar to visual studio) of development in c#/asp.net to linux operating systems?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: use Mono and MonoDevelop. ASP.NET itself I don't believe can be run on a linux operating system.  Mod_Mono adds the support for ASP.NET I would argue its not actually ASP.NET

Comment: ASP.NET vNext can run on Linux. Correct me if not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://monodevelop.com/ -- For developing software in Linux with ASP.NET MVC and C#

Comment: this support sftp connection?!

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano - I don't know does Apache support it?

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano, there are SFTP libraries for Mono, if that's what you're asking.  I'm not sure if there are any free ones, though.

Comment: This is for future reference.  I just saw this post and went to download the software (I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and saw the following message for the Ubuntu download on their website:

`Packages for MonoDevelop 4.2.2 not yet available. The latest available version is MonoDevelop 2.6.0.1`

This version is recommended for 10.04, and may no longer be a viable option for ASP.NET or C#.

Comment: You don't have to use monodevelop, could use latest mono libs w/ emacs or sublime

Answer (score 1):

Also for Linux have Visual Studio Code : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs?dv=linux64